# groups, generators, and orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think I have a problem connecting the dots here:
Suppose $G$ is any group, and $g,h \in G$ and $h \in \langle g\rangle$. If $ord(g) = s$ and $ord(h) = t$, need to prove $t$ divides $s$.

I understand that $g$ is a generator of $G$ and for every $x \in G, x = g^n$ for some integer $n$. Does it have to be the case $G$ is cyclic? Since $ord(g) = s$, then $\langle g\rangle$ = $\{e, g, g^2,…g^{s-1}\}$ and $|\langle g\rangle | = s$. Since $h \in \langle g\rangle$, then $h$ is some power of $g$, or $h = g^m$, where $0 \le m \le s-1$. Since $ord(h) = t$, we can substitute $h^t =(g^m)^t = g^{mt} = e$. We also have $s$ being the least positive integer s.t. $g^s = e$ and $m < s$. So does it mean from the above that $t$ divides $s$?

Comment: $$h\in\langle g\rangle\implies \langle h\rangle \le \langle g\rangle$$ and now just apply Lagrange's theorem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $(g^m)^s=(g^s)^m=e^m=e$, so $t\le s$. Suppose $t$ does not divide $s$, so $\gcd(t,s)<t$.It is a theorem that there exist integers $a,b$ such that $at+bs=\gcd(t,s)$. Thus 
$$g^{m\gcd(t,s)}=g^{amt+bms}=((g^m)^t)^a(g^s)^{bm}=e^ae^{bm}=e$$
so $t$ cannot be the smallest positive integer such that $(g^m)^t=e$.

Comment: @Bob The easiest way to get from $t\le s$ to $t\mid s$ I know of is the proof I gave, but if you have a better one I'd love to see it. The theorem is [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) by the way, and is an elementary result in number theory.